# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Underflow in restore - more restores than saves

Tags: dialog, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

While Creating the custom dialog in Jetpack compose we are getting the crash, below is crash log:

`Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Underflow in restore - more restores than saves at android.graphics.Canvas.restore(Canvas.java:681) at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.AndroidCanvas.restore(AndroidCanvas.android.kt:85) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.draw-x_KDEd0$ui_release(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:127) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:370) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:359) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:367) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:359) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:866) at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.performDraw(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:151) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:367) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:359) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawContent(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:64) at androidx.compose.ui.draw.DrawBackgroundModifier.draw(DrawModifier.kt:115) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.draw-x_KDEd0$ui_release(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:92) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:370) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:359) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:367) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:359) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:866) at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.performDraw(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:151) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:367) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:359) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawContent(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:64) at androidx.compose.foundation.Background.draw(Background.kt:107) at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.draw(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:361) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.draw-x_KDEd0$ui_release(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:92) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:370) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:359) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:866) at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.performDraw(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:151) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:367) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:359) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:367) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.access$drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:58) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:396) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:395) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2200) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:234) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230) at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341) at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(:1) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230) at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:395) at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:58) at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeApi29.record(RenderNodeApi29.android.kt:209) at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.updateDisplayList(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:301) at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchDraw(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1046) at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22776) at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21597) at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4579) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4552) at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21547) at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4579) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4552) at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21547) at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4579) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4552) at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21547) at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4579) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4552) at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21547) at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:559) at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:565) at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:642) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4364) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:4074) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3329) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2129) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8603) at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:975) at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:799) at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:734) at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:960) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7864) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)`

Compose version we are using is:

```
const val composeBom = "2023.01.00"
const val composeMaterial3 = "1.1.2"
const val composeLifecycleRuntime = "2.6.1"
const val composeConstraintLayout = "1.0.1"
```

Let me know if anyone faced this issue.

Custom compose dialog should not crash on load in composable functions

Comment: Hey Priya!  Have you tried updating the compose dependencies? I think updating the `composeBom` to version **[2023.10.01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom/bom-mapping)**, compose compiler to version **[1.5.6](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler)**, and `composeLifecycleRuntime` to version **[2.6.2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle)** might solve the issue.